# Cell.getValue is not comparing values correctly

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, comparison-operators

I am new to google apps script, and I am running into a problem. When I am trying to compare a cell value to two integers, it works every time. On my spreadsheet, there are only a few values that fit into these constraints. Here is my code:

```
  function CHECK_CORRELATION() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
    var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
    var lastRow = rangeData.getNumRows();
    var counter = 0;
    var counter2 = 0;
    var values = rangeData.getValues()
    for (var j = 2; j <= lastRow; j++){
      var cell = sheet.getRange(j, 8)
      if (cell.isBlank()) {
        continue;
      } else {
        if (0.9<=cell.getValue()<=1.1){
          Logger.log(cell.getValue());
          counter++;
        }
        counter2++;
      }
    }
    Logger.log(counter)
    Logger.log(counter2)
    if (counter>(counter2/2)) {
      return "The idea that a student will have motivation and has a part time job co-occur"
    } else {
      return "The idea that a student will have motivation and has a part time job does not co-occur"
    }
  }
```

[This is the logger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjO2Q.png)

It shows that counter is 62 *and* counter2 is 62, even though it shouldn't be.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already going great! I just cleaned up your for loop a bit. 
I'm assuming your data is in the 8th column, right?

Let me know if this solved your problem.

```js
function CHECK_CORRELATION() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lc = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var rangeData = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lr -1, lc);
  var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = rangeData.getNumRows();
  var counter = 0;
  var counter2 = 0;
  var values = rangeData.getValues();
  
  for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++)
  {
    var row = values[j];
    var dataToCheck = row[7];
    if ((dataToCheck != "" || dataToCheck != undefined) && dataToCheck >= 0.9 && dataToCheck <= 1.1)
    {
      counter++;
      }
      else
      {
        counter2++;
      }
      
    }
  
  Logger.log(counter)
  Logger.log(counter2)
  if (counter>(counter2/2)) 
  {
    return "The idea that a student will have motivation and has a part time job co-occur"
  } 
  else 
  {
    return "The idea that a student will have motivation and has a part time job does not co-occur"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly. I just have a few questions. Why do you do lr-1, and why do you check if dataToCheck is undefined? Does that mean that it is an integer divided by 0?

Comment: Happy to hear! 
getLastRow returns the last row in your dataset. So if you have a header and 62 rows of data, getLastRow returns 63. But in this case, we want it to loop only trough the data so -1 for the header.

'dataToCheck != undefined' might be a little overkill, but since I struggled with it in the past, I almost automaticly also check for undefined just to be sure. You could leave it out of course, won't change much for you probably.

Answer (score 0):

This expression doesn't work as you think:

```
0.9<=cell.getValue()<=1.1
```

The above because `<=` is a [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) that requires two operands so the expression is comparing the the result of the first comparison (true or false) with a number.

Try replacing the above expression with

```
0.9 <= cell.getValue() && cell.getValue() <= 1.1
```

`&&` is the [logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) `AND`